# Copying files, Windows 260 character path length limit, can a Linux system bypass this?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, path

As many of us may know, windows has a limit to how many characters can be in the destination of where you can paste a file this is destination folder+file name, 255 xp, 256 vista, 260 seven and up.

And this is a pain for many of us, so in my attempt to find a way around this, I found 1 method that normally would work but didn't for me, robocopy.

So being a fan of linux, I thought I'd look up on google what it's max copy/paste character limit, but to no avail have I found results.

So I figured I'd take the easy way out to finding my answer.

Can you copy/paste files with a destination folder+file name that's more than 260 characters with linux such as ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/833299) will help, as also [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits).

Comment: Well thank you for that, although I was looking for a more specified answer such as the limit of ubuntu is XXXX, but should it not be enough at least I know how to change it.

Comment: Karan, I found out the ubuntu limit is indeed more than high enough at it's preset to do so, but I ran into another error, cannot copy special files, any ideas there.

Comment: What "special files"?

Comment: I'd have to reinstall ubuntu again and attempt transfer again which I wont have time to do till next week, but I'm pretty sure it said that for more than a few files.

Comment: `255 xp, 256 vista, 260 seven and up` that's completely wrong. The MAX_PATH value in Windows has always been 260. However it's just the limit of the old Win32 APIs due to legacy issues from DOS. Internally the real limit is **32767 characters** which can be bypassed by adding a \\?\ prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has ext4 filesystem by default (or ext3 in old versions). Most modern Linux systems prefer ext4 as their default filesystem. Neither ext3 or ext4 filesystem has any limit on maximum pathname length.